# Symfony2, Doctrine2, findBy() order not working

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I created a repository for my Articles entity and I'm trying to get all values ordered by ID DESC. But, I'll get everytime values ordered by id ASC. Here is my <kbd>ArticleRepository.php</kbd>:

```
<?php

namespace Acme\BlogBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;

class ArticleRepository extends EntityRepository
{
    public function findAll()
    {
        return $this->findBy(array(), array('id' => 'DESC'));
    }

    public function findOneBySlug($slug)
    {
        $query = $this->getEntityManager()
                      ->createQuery('
                          SELECT p FROM AcmePagesBundle:Article a
                          WHERE a.slug = :slug
                      ')
                      ->setParameter('slug', $slug);

        try {
            return $query->getSingleResult();
        } catch (\Doctrine\ORM\NoResultException $e) {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The Syntax looks good. This should provide a set of well ordered articles.

First, make sure the @Entity annotation is set with the right Repository class within the Article Entity,

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="...");
 */
class Article
{
    // ...
}
```

Also, if you want to use native helpers, you've just to call `findBy` from the `ArticleRepository` within your controller,

```
 $articles = $this->get('doctrine')
      ->getRepository('YourBundle:Article')
      ->findBy(array(), array('id' => 'DESC'));
```

Comment: Thanks there is the problem. I didn't had `repositoryClass()` parameter in my entity. Thanks.

Comment: It worth to clarify something about this code. In order you can create and use your own queries, you have to point out the relation like @Ahmed explain in the first part of his code, but the second part ...findBy(...), doesn't need the first part of the code, since you are calling a function "findBy", that belongs to Symfony/Doctrine functionality.

Comment: in lase example there is missing `)` before `;`

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to create a query in ArticleRepostory.php for that

In your controller you can just do:

```
$entities = $em->getRepository('YourBundle:Article')->findBy(array(), array( 'id' => 'DESC' ));
```

---

```
->findBy(array(), array( 'id' => 'DESC' )); // Order Works  
->findAll(array(), array( 'id' => 'DESC' )); // Order doesn't work
```

Comment: Why is it better than changing the order of standard `findAll`? And what if you needed it in a few places?

Comment: @meze in reality findAll doesn't receive any parameters, if you see the code (symfony2 code) findAll call findBy(array()).

Comment: Yes it works, but why? It's only same method but in shorter version. (now I god a explanation, so I'll give you upvote, because your solution works too)

Comment: @user8542214 If I understand well you now know why, but just in case another user don't. The reason was you didn't associate your class Article to the repository class ArticleRepository, so at the end you was really calling symfony/doctrine findall();

Answer (score 1):

This should be work:

```
public function findAll()
{
    $em = $this->getEntityManager();

    $query = $em->createQuery('
        SELECT *
        FROM AcmePagesBundle:Article a
        ORDER BY a.id DESC
    ');

    return $query->getResult();
}
```

Comment: It should yes, but findBy do the same with shorter and more flexible version.

Answer (score 0):

I would tend to do this in my repository (to allow for using the same select DQL in different methods in the repository - especially when you have lots of fetch-joins to include):

```php
class FooRepository extends EntityRepository
{
    /**
     * Get the DQL to select Foos with all joins
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getSelectDql()
    {
        $dql = '
               SELECT f
                 FROM Entity:Foo f
        ';

        return $dql;
    }

    /**
     * Fetch all foos, ordered
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function fetchAllOrdered()
    {
        $dql = sprintf(
            '%s %s',
            $this->getSelectDql(),
            'ORDER BY f.id DESC'
        );

        return $this->getEntityManager()
            ->createQuery($dql)
            ->getResult();
    }
}
```

This should make your repository quite flexible, allow different ordering in different methods (if you need to order them differently) and keep all DB-related code out of your controller.

Answer (score 0):

Symfony `3.3` find by order working example.

From your controller:

```
public function indexAction(){
     $entityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
     $categoryRepository = $entityManager->getRepository(ProductCategory::class); 
     $items = $categoryRepository->findBy(array(), array('id' => 'DESC'));
     ....
}
```